# Is this description of space complexity accurate?

Tags: algorithm

I am working on a report and an author has written the following section about space complexity:

> Space complexity is the amount of space something takes up. There are two ways to look at instruction and data.
>   With today’s computers, instruction space—or how much code is required—is the less important of the two.
>   It applied most when storage space was extremely costly, and every character counted. Today’s terabyte-sized hard drives make this less relevant, but short code is still more readable and usually faster.
>   The second, and more important, is data space. This is the memory required to run an algorithm. As the algorithm processes, it requires memory storage. If there is too much data handled with each iteration of the process, it can crash a computer.
>   All things being equal, algorithms that require little instruction and data space are best.

According to me, this is borderline factually incorrect, because a processor's cache is still limited, and the size of the instructions still do matter. Infact today you are more likey to run out of processor cache than RAM with your algorithm. However, I am not sure my notion is correct, and I want to have some solid points to discuss before I bring this up with the author who wrote the section and ask for edits.

Comment: Instruction space isn't a factor in space *complexity*; it doesn't grow with the size of the input.

Comment: @user2357112: "Complexity" doesn't require any relationship with the size of the input. It's merely that we're usually interested in complexities that *do* grow with the size of the input; but that can be deceptive. An algorithm that takes 1 day + 2 ms/GB of input will have greater time complexity than algorithm that takes 2 s/GB of input until the input is in the tens of terabytes.

Comment: @ruakh I understand what you're getting at (in the real world, the coefficients matter), but you don't get to change the definition of “time complexity”. The time complexities of both of your hypothetical algorithms are O(N).

Comment: @robmayoff: Sorry, but you are simply mistaken. (In a very interesting way, actually: your comment consists of three statements that are each completely correct, and yet the comment as a whole is completely wrong!) In short: big-O notation is an incredibly useful way to talk about complexity, but it's not part of the definition at all. A time complexity of 2n is not the same as a time complexity of 3n, even though both are O(n).

Comment: @robmayoff: (That said, I'll admit that it's not 100% kosher to describe an algorithm as taking a certain amount of time, with actual units of time instead of something abstract like "steps"; rather, what takes literal time is a given implementation of the algorithm, e.g. a certain program compiled with certain compiler settings and run on a certain machine. One major benefit of big-O notation is that it sidesteps all of that.)

Comment: To the OP: I suggest you move your question to https://cs.stackexchange.com/. Stack Overflow is wonderful, but as you can see from all the upvotes to rob mayoff's completely-wrong comment above, there's a very pervasive misunderstanding of the term "[complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity)" among programmers, including even very-high-rep Stack Overflow users. The answers you get here will be skewed accordingly. The folks on the CS Stack Exchange site are more likely to know the actual definition and answer accordingly.

Comment: @ruakh Thank you, I will try to move this question there, or start a new question. Thank you for all the answers here. I understand this is a complex and not-so-well understood topic, but every discussion helps.